# golang pythonic string construction

Tags: python, string, constructor, go

In python strings can be created in a manner of `"%s times %d is %s" % ('money', 2, 'something') == 'money times 2 is something'`

And then in golang samples there is quite in few places (from http example):

`fmt.Printf("%s %s %s\n", r.RemoteAddr, r.Method, r.URL)`

So from first sight it appears similar but that's just for console output. What about constructing strings to pass somewhere? Can something like this be used inline as in manner of: `http.ListenAndServe("%s:%s", op.Host, op.Port, Log(http.DefaultServeMux))`

P.S. maybe there is any good reads for python to golang?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, seems clear to me...

Comment: *golang pythonic* :-)

Comment: @plg, thanks, voting as well to close it since it is dublicate. Don't want to delete it since it's still a pointer to correct answer with different name question.